# can't read "big" structure with read()

Tags: c++

I have a structure and want to write information and then get one.

```
struct st
{
    char something[21];
    char something2[21];
    ...
}

void input (st &data)
{
    ...
    std::fstream fl(filename, std::ios::out);
    ...
    while(...)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter sth: ";
        std::cin >> data.something;
        ...
        fl.write ((char*) &data, sizeof(data));
    }
    fl.close();
}

void output (st &data)
{
    ...
    std::fstream fl(filename, std::ios::out | std::ios::in);
    ...
    fl.read ((char*) &data, sizeof(data));
    while (!fl.eof())
    {
        std::cout << data.something << std::endl;
        ...
        fl.read ((char*) &data, sizeof(data));
    }
    ...
    fl.close();
}
```

In example I have two elements in struct and together its size is 42 bytes. When I add more variables, so, that its size will be 165 bytes I still can see on colsole what is in the file, but when its size is more than 165 bytes, I can see nothing.
When I entered to debug mode I found out that in

```
output()
```

function in loop `while(!fl.eof())` there is no entrance.

I can't understand why function `read()` do not read data from the file.
I took this code from an exapmle and insert one to mine:

```
std::cout << "Reading " << sizeof(data) << " characters... ";
fl.read ((char*) &data, sizeof(data));

if (fl)
    std::cout << "all characters read successfully.";
else
    std::cout << "error: only " << fl.gcount() << " could be read.";
```

I ran it and get:

```
Reading 216 characters... error: only 52 could be read.
```

Why? Input was correct. I didn't exceed char array size while enter information.

**Edited. I add a full code...**
Here is a full code.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iterator>

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
struct st_general
{
    struct
    {
        char name[21];
        char surname[21];
        char patronym[21];
        char group[9];
        char sex[2];
        char book_num[7];
        char birth_date[9];     // DD.MM.YY
    }main;

    struct
    {
        char town[21];
        char district[21];
        char street[21];
        char built_num[7];
    }loc;
/**
    struct
    {
        char phone_num_1[11];
        char phone_num_2[11];
    }cont;
*/
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template <typename T>
void normalize (std::string sent, T &value) // link(?) to a value
{
    std::cout << sent;
    std::cin.getline(value, sizeof(value));
    *std::prev(std::end(value)) = '\0';
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void input_inf (st_general &data)
{
    char *filename = "little_snake.txt";

    int clean;
    std::cout << "Clean the file? 0 - No, otherwise - Yes: ";
    std::cin >> clean;

    std::fstream fl(filename, (clean ? (std::ios::out) : (std::ios::out | std::ios::app)));

    if (!fl)
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR::WRITING::UNABLE::TO::CREATE::OR::OPEN::FILE";
        exit(true);
    }

    int want;
    std::cout << "Enter information? 0 - No, otherwise - Yes: ";
    std::cin >> want;

    std::cin.get();

    // Enter information into the file
    while (want)
    {
        normalize ("Enter name: ", data.main.name);
        normalize ("Enter surname: ", data.main.surname);
        normalize ("Enter patronym: ", data.main.patronym);
        normalize ("Enter group: ", data.main.group);
        normalize ("Enter sex (M, F): ", data.main.sex);
        normalize ("Enter book number: ", data.main.book_num);
        normalize ("Enter birth date: ", data.main.birth_date);

        normalize ("Enter town: ", data.loc.town);
        normalize ("Enter district: ", data.loc.district);
        normalize ("Enter street: ", data.loc.street);
        normalize ("Enter built number: ", data.loc.built_num);
/**
        normalize ("Enter phone number 1: ", data.cont.phone_num_1);
        normalize ("Enter phone number 2: ", data.cont.phone_num_2);
*/
        fl.write((char*) &data, sizeof(data));
        std::cout << "Input 0 to cancel: ";
        std::cin >> want;
    }

    fl.close();
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void output_inf(st_general &data)
{
    char *filename = "little_snake.txt";
    std::fstream fl(filename, std::ios::out | std::ios::in);

    if (!fl)
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR::READING::UNABLE::TO::OPEN::FILE";
        exit(true);
    }
    std::cout << " ______________________ ______________________ ______________________ __________ ___ ________ __________ ______________________ ______________________ ______________________ ________ ____________ ____________\n"
              << "|         Name         |       Surname        |       Patronym       |  group   | S | book_n |  birth   |         town         |       district       |        street        | built  |   phone    |   phone    |\n"
              << "|______________________|______________________|______________________|__________|___|________|__________|______________________|______________________|______________________|________|____________|____________|\n";

    std::cout << "Reading " << sizeof(data) << " characters... ";
    fl.read ((char*) &data, sizeof(data));

    if (fl)
        std::cout << "all characters read successfully.\n";
    else
        std::cout << "error: only " << fl.gcount() << " could be read.\n";

    // reading from the file
    while (!fl.eof())
    {
        std::cout << "|"
                  << std::setw(21) << data.main.name         << " |"
                  << std::setw(21) << data.main.surname      << " |"
                  << std::setw(21) << data.main.patronym     << " |"
                  << std::setw(9)  << data.main.group        << " |"
                  << std::setw(2)  << data.main.sex          << " |"
                  << std::setw(7)  << data.main.book_num     << " |"
                  << std::setw(9)  << data.main.birth_date   << " |"

                  << std::setw(21) << data.loc.town          << " |"
                  << std::setw(21) << data.loc.district      << " |"
                  << std::setw(21) << data.loc.street        << " |"
                  << std::setw(7)  << data.loc.built_num     << " |"
/**
                  << std::setw(11) << data.cont.phone_num_1  << " |"
                  << std::setw(11) << data.cont.phone_num_2  << " |"
*/
                  << std::endl
                  << "|______________________|______________________|______________________|__________|___|________|__________|______________________|______________________|______________________|________|____________|____________|\n";

        fl.read ((char*) &data, sizeof(data));
    }

    fl.close();
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main ()
{
//    system("chcp 1251>null");   // to support Russian language
    st_general cs17;

    input_inf (cs17);
    output_inf (cs17);

    _getch();

    return 0;
}
```

And now if you uncomment a part of code in structure, input and ouput functions and try to write to and then read from you'll get an error. Not more than 165 bytes...

Comment: It's not obvious from just this much where the problem is. Please see if you can reduce your whole program to a [mcve].

Comment: Though it's good to be extra careful using raw character arrays. `std::cin >> data.something;` should be more like `std::cin.getline(data.something, sizeof(data.something));`. Could also `*std::prev(std::end(data.something)) = '\0';` after reading from file in case of a corrupt file.

Comment: In C++ try and steer towards `std::string` and away from C-style fixed-length buffers. You're probably exceeding the length of these buffers so egregiously your program gets trashed. I'm also not convinced that under a hundred bytes is "big" in an era where cheap laptops have *billions* of bytes of memory.

Comment: Looping on "not EOF" is an anti-pattern. Don't do it. It doesn't work like you think it does, and it doesn't catch a whole class of other read failures.

Comment: @cdhowie, so, what should I use instead?

Comment: @cdhowie, interesting. When I disable a loop, so, now it executes once, I got an error (not all characters were read) but I got information. Not correct, but got it.
I would be thankful if you suggest what to use instead of "not EOF"

Comment: Can't help but notice you're not opening the file in binary mode.  On Windows this means any stray `\26` (ctrl-z) will terminate input with an EOF, and line endings will be translated leading to a potential loss of data. If you're on Windows this may be your issue. `while (!fl.eof())` will also lead to unhappiness. Test if your input operations succeed or fail, not for EOF.

Answer (score -2):

A solution is an intrresting one. At least as of now I can't find anything better.
It was noticed that when you almost fill an array of characters, this information is read successfully. So, I created a function. This one adds '\0' symbols to your input or cuts it if you enter more symbols than array can consist.

After that all characters are read without any problems.

Thank you all :)).

Comment: It doesn't sound right. You should wait for a proper solution.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, yeah, I know. But can't found anything. It was said above to use std::string, but how, if a structure size must be constant, as I understand.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, instead of space symbols the function add '\0' symbols. And it works correct :)).